# running a batch gradient descent optimizer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I want to train a model using tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer() in a batch mode.
Consider the following code snippet:

```
iteration = 50

x1_data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
x2_data = [[1.5,2.5],[2.5,3.5],[3.5,4.5],[4.5,5.5]]
y_data = [[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]

X_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1,2))
X_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1,2))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,2))

Y_predicted = # f(X_1,X_2) 

loss = tf.norm(Y - Y_predicted,ord='euclidean' , name = "loss")

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.1 ).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(iterations):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={(X_1,X_2): ([np.reshape(data,(1,2)) for data in x1_data], [np.reshape(data,(1,2)) for data in x2_data]),Y: [np.reshape(data,(1,2)) for data in y_data]})
```

I have two inputs `x1_data` and `x2_data`, each is a list of vectors (for example word vectors), and a list of vectors as an output, `y_data`. In order to do a **batch** training, I need to feed `X_1` with `x1_data` and `X_2` with `x2_data`. I would like to know how to define the corresponding placeholders and how to pass `x1_data` and `x2_data` lists in `feed_dict`? forget about `f` function by now. This code gives an error anyway, I already played around the code, and it did not work. For the mentioned code the following error arises:

```
ValueError: Could not flatten dictionary. Key had 2 elements, but value had 8 elements. Key: [<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>], value: [array([[1, 2]]), array([[2, 3]]), array([[3, 4]]), array([[4, 5]]), array([[1, 2]]), array([[2, 3]]), array([[3, 4]]), array([[4, 5]])].
```

So, the problem is with input data `x1_data` and `x2_data`.

Thanks

---

The second problem is that:

The `f` function in the code is as follows:

```
alfa = tf.ones([1,2])    
temp_1 = tf.matmul(X_1,tf.reshape(tensor,[2,2*2]))
temp_2 = tf.matmul(X_2,tf.reshape(tensor,[2,2*2]))
temp = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(temp_1,[2,2]),tf.reshape(temp_2,[2,2]))
Y_predicted = tf.matmul(alfa,temp)
```

In which `tensor` is a 2*2*2 variable tensor, and `alfa` is a constant 1*2 vector to finally get a 1*2 vector for `Y_predicted`.
In stochastic case, the above code seems to work, since `X_1` and `X_2` are 1*2 vectors taken from an input sample each time. In batch mode, however, I get a (None,1,2) tensor for `X_1` and `X_2` which cannot be multiplied with the reshape of the `tensor`. Do you know how to reformulate the code to work in batch case?

I am not sure if the following changes give me the expected output:

```
alfa = tf.ones([4,1,2])
temp_1 = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X_1,(4,1*2)),tf.reshape(tensor,[2,4]))
temp_2 = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X_2,(4,1*2)),tf.reshape(tensor,[2,4]))
temp = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(temp_1,[4,2,2]),tf.reshape(temp_2,[4,2,2]))
Y_predicted = tf.matmul(alfa,temp)
```

Thanks

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: @YilunZhang I edited the post.

Comment: Try changing `feed_dict` to `{X_1: [np.reshape(data,(1,2)) for data in x1_data], X_2: [np.reshape(data,(1,2)) for data in x2_data], Y: [np.reshape(data,(1,2)) for data in y_data]}`, the `(X_1, X_2) : (...)` looks suspicious to me

Comment: @GPhilo thanks! I wanted to make a tuple!! Now, do you have any idea how can I extract each element of the X_1 and X_2 for the function f? in function f, each input vector is supposed to be multiplied by a tensor to output a matrix.

Comment: indeed, if your batch has 4 samples, your placeholder should have one dimension for the sample size (the first one) which is `None` (to make batch size changeable without having to rewrite the network structure)

Comment: @GPhilo Yes, I already put `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1,2))`. May I add the problem below the main post to make my question clear?

Comment: That's what you should do, yeah ;)

Comment: @GPhilo thanks, do you have any idea of the second problem?